# How to turn off "JSS Development Workflow"?

Tags: jss, workflow

We recently switched from code-first to `Sitecore-first` in our `JSS` project.

In the `Sitecore-first` approach we now use `Unicorn` to serialize/sync Sitecore structure and content.

However the `JSS` Development Workflow is still in effect when creating a new item.

How can I deactivate this workflow completely?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable workflow entirely across your JSS templates and existing items, you can use the following bit of Sitecore PowerShell to clear the `Default workflow` on templates, and the `Workflow` and `Workflow state` on content items.

Note that this script totally removes all workflow from the referenced content and template paths, so use with care if you have other existing workflows you wish to preserve.

```powershell
$contentRoot = Get-Item "master:\content\jss-react-sample"
$templatesRoot = Get-Item "master:\templates\Project\jss-react-sample"

# Disable workflow on the templates
$templatesCount = 0
$templatesRoot | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -eq "__Standard Values" } | % {
    $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $_.Fields["__Default workflow"].Reset()
    $_.Editing.EndEdit() | out-null
    $templatesCount++
}
Write-Host "Updated $templatesCount templates"

# Remove workflow on existing content
$contentCount = 0
$contentRoot | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | % {
    $_.Editing.BeginEdit()
    $_.Fields["__Workflow"].Reset()
    $_.Fields["__Workflow state"].Reset()
    $_.Editing.EndEdit() | out-null
    $contentCount++
}
Write-Host "Updated $contentCount content items"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Checked the script on my local machine and can now create a new Item that does not have the Default JSS Workflow when I check the workflow fields. However, is still see the warning message explaining that the Item will be overridden in the next Jss Import. Will deleting the JSS Development Workflow remove this message, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: @Jan-Pieter That warning is independent from the workflow, since even after removing the workflow (actually, especially after removing) the import could still overwrite those items. You can remove it by ensuring that the import user (`sitecore\JssImport` by default) does not have write access to the app/site item tree.

Comment: @techphoria414 I cannot find this user on our prod environment. Still getting this warning message. Can there be some other reason for this?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way will be just removing the Default workflow from the existing template's standard value and update/enable it back when needed. Also the new templates needs to be created without any default workflow and setup later when needed.

Note - If you have lot of existing templates, can try execute a power-shell command to set/revoke default workflow.

[image]

Anyways you are planning to go with Sitecore first and Unicorn for content sync, so nothing will overwrite your template changes until you revert back.

As an additional note the default workflow for jss app is set in the \Website\App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices\Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Apps.config file,

Anyways no update required here in your case, as you are planning for Sitecore first with Unicorn.

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable this warning (assuming you have already disabled the JSS Development Workflow as others have answered):

[image]

I have found this is triggered by the pipeline, defined in `\App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices\Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.config`

```
<getContentEditorWarnings>
  <processor type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.ShowJssNotifications, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices" resolve="true" />
</getContentEditorWarnings>
```

Either you can **disable/remove** the pipeline via config patch, or, by decompiling the code and reviewing its logic I can see that this is checking for Write access for the `sitecore\jssimport` user

```
    using (new UserSwitcher(User.FromName(appConfiguration.ImportUser, isAuthenticated: false)))
    {
        if (contextItem.Access.CanWrite())
        {
            args.Notifications.Add(new Notification
            {
                Title = Translate.Text("The current item is allowed to be overwritten during next import."),
                Description = Translate.Text("If this is unexpected, please move the item to Content Mode workflow state or protect it against overwrite using JSS Import security presets.")
            });
        }
    }
```

The way to do this is to remove this security setting from your JSS site (sitecore > content > yourSiteName)

[image]

If you do this, be aware that `JssImport` user inherits from `sitecore\Author` role (among others) so if you have granted `Write permission` for this then you would have to `Deny Write permission` for JssImport.